# Predicate logic - are these two formulas equivalent?

Tags: predicate-logic

Are these two logical formulas logically equivalent or not? What I am asking is whether these two formulas mean the same thing or not.

(1) ∃x ∀y ((A(x) ∧ B(y)) → ¬C(x, y) )

(2) ∃x (A(x) ∧ ∀y (B(y) → ¬C(x, y) ))

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does $A(x)\land B(y)\rightarrow\neg C(x,y)$ mean $(A(x)\land B(y))\rightarrow\neg C(x,y)$ or does it mean $A(x)\land(B(y)\rightarrow\neg C(x,y))$?

Comment: (1) means (A(x) ∧ B(y)) → ¬C(x,y), I'll edit it to clarify.

Comment: If $A(x)$ is false for all $x,$ then (1) is true but (2) is false. So the two formulas are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a universe where $A(x)$ never holds. What are the truth values of the two statements?